# 'Run command as login shell' in LXTerminal

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, rvm, lxterminal

So I'm trying to get RVM setup on Lubuntu using instructions [here](http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/linux?back=choose_your_operating_system). They say to change my shell settings, but the UI of Lubuntu / LXTerminal doesn't have that option (as far as I could see). If I try to go without it, I get errors later on, saying pretty much the same thing. If I try to look up help, it says pretty much the [same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336596/rvm-installation-not-working-rvm-is-not-a-function). What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`man lxterminal`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/lxterminal.1.html):

```
-l --loginshell
       Executes login shell.
```

You have to start the terminal manually with the `-l` option.

But that is pointless, since you can always run a login shell easily using:

```
bash -l
```

from a terminal which is not running a login shell. So everytime you open a new shell while installing, start a login shell using `bash -l`. This is only needed until you logout or restart.

Comment: I think it worked. Give me a minute to check. Is there anyway to make it start that way by default? EDIT: It worked! Thank you!

Comment: @RomanDavis you can have a look at this: http://rvm.io/integration/lxterminal